# Get Object attribute with array Notation inside ember template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

Just trying something but not sure how to do it.

Scenario:- I'm trying to render a page which have a configuration data and view data, so basically My template loop on the configuration data to render page and fetch value from view data to display.

so my model have something like

```
 model:{'confData':[{'displayName':'value1','fieldName':'Field1'},
                    {repeat similar object}
                   ],
        'viewData':{'Field1':'value1','Field2':'value2',....}
        }
```

Now in template I'm trying to render like:

```
{{#each confData}}
  this.displayName {{input type='text' value=viewData[this.fieldName] }}
{{/each}}
```

but it does not accept it. Any suggestion on how I can deal with this sort of problem.

PS: the confdata and view data in actual application will be api call which i can't change.
I saw somthing like http://jsfiddle.net/GRaa5/4/ but when I tried changing as http://jsfiddle.net/weyzay5v/ it failed.

Thanks.

Comment: you can't use `this` inside templates...

Comment: @CodeJack but I did and it worked. here's the modified sample http://jsfiddle.net/n88g48rp/

Comment: @CodeJack `this` definitely works in templates. It doesn't refer to the same thing as it does in JS though. In templates, it refers to the current context (which can be changed with block helpers).

Comment: ^ yep thats wat i meant..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do what you want purely with Handlebars. Remember that Handlebars templates are logic-less and for presentation only. My suggestion would be to make a computed property in your controller:

```
data: function() {
    var confData = this.get('confData');
    var viewData = this.get('viewData');

    return confData.map(function(data) {
        return {
            displayName: data.displayName,
            value: viewData[data.filedName]
        };
    });
}.property('confData.[]', 'viewData')
```

Then in your template:

```
{{#each data}}
    {{displayName}} {{input type='text' value=value}}
{{/each}}
```